# Change color of menu item and hamburger icon

Tags: android, hamburger-menu

I'm using the default drawerlayout template for an android app. The problem is that it comes out with white icons instead of black. How do I change that?

Comment: put your code for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Android's generated Menu Icons like the Hamburger Icon and the menu item create a style like so:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
```